# Immutable struct with mutable reference members

Tags: rust

Is my understanding correct that in Rust it is not possible to protect reference members of a struct from modification while having the reference target values mutable? (Without runtime borrow checking that is.) For example:

```rust
struct MyData<'a> {
    pub some_ref: &'a mut i32,
}

fn doit<'a>(data: &mut MyData<'a>, other_ref: &'a mut i32) {
    // I want to be able to do the following here:
    *data.some_ref = 22;
    // but make it impossible to do the following:
    data.some_ref = other_ref;
}
```

Not being able to change the reference value may be useful in certain FFI situations. FFI and the performance requirements reasons prevent the use of runtime borrow checking here.

In C++ it can be expressed like this:

```cpp
struct MyData {
    int* const some_ref;
};

void doit(const MyData &data, int* other_ref) {
    // this is allowed:
    *data.some_ref = 22;
    // this is not:
    data.some_ref = other_ref; // compile error
}
```

Comment: Do you change the reference _only_ through FFI? What about initialization?

Comment: Imagine a program where the main part of it allocates the `MyData` struct and then loads two dynamic libraries. It gives these 2 dynamic libs pointers to the allocated `MyData` and allows the libs to access and change the value pointed at by the `some_ref` field (it takes care of ensuring they don't do it at the same time), but it must prevent them from changing the `some_ref` reference itself, because for its own reasons it must ensure that the data is located at that specific address where it allocated it. I bet one can come up with an example that does not involve dylibs too.

Comment: If you want protection against intentional misuse, this is not something Rust can provide (think unsafe code, rustc bugs, `/proc/mem` and friends). If you just want to protect again accidental misuse, this is another story.

Comment: All misuse. Accidental included.

Comment: Then your C++ code isn't correct. Code can cast the `const` away and assign to the reference.

Comment: Let's say accidental. The C++ example shows what I'd like to achieve--a compile time error if attempted to change the pointer as opposed to the target value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a wrapper type around the reference. If the constructor is private, and so is the wrapped reference field, you cannot replace the reference itself. You can then implement [`DerefMut`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/ops/trait.DerefMut.html) to allow changing the referent.

```rust
pub struct ImmRef<'a> {
    inner: &'a mut i32,
}

impl<'a> ImmRef<'a> {
    fn new(inner: &'a mut i32) -> Self { Self { inner } }
}

impl std::ops::Deref for ImmRef<'_> {
    type Target = i32;
    fn deref(&self) -> &Self::Target { &*self.inner }
}
impl std::ops::DerefMut for ImmRef<'_> {
    fn deref_mut(&mut self) -> &mut Self::Target { &mut *self.inner }
}

struct MyData<'a> {
    pub some_ref: ImmRef<'a>,
}

fn doit<'a>(data: &mut MyData<'a>, other_ref: &'a mut i32) {
    // I want to be able to do the following here:
    *data.some_ref = 22;
    // but make it impossible to do the following:
    // data.some_ref = other_ref;
}
```

You can mark the newtype `#[repr(transparent)]` for FFI purposes.

But do note that if the code has some `ImmRef<'a>` available it can use tools such as `std::mem::replace()` to replace the reference.

Comment: Yes, this is the solution I was looking for. The only potential problem here is that if somehow somewhere you got an individual `ImmRef` value--you can still assign it into the `MyData::some_ref` field. However, this is not a problem if you only see `ImmRef`s as members of other structs that you don't own (so you can't move it out from another struct and you don't implement `Copy` for it). Thanks!

Comment: @LevHimmelfarb If you have two mutable instances of `MyData` you can swap their references.

Answer (score 0):

Rust does not allow you to specify the mutability of individual fields like you can via `const` in C++. Instead, you should simply *encapsulate* the data by making it private and only allow modification through methods that you dictate:

```
struct MyData<'a> {
    some_ref: &'a mut i32,
}

impl MyData<'_> {
    pub fn set_ref(&mut self, other: i32) {
        *self.some_ref = other;
    }
}
```

That way, the field `some_ref` cannot be modified directly (outside of the module) and must use the available method.

Comment: This _could_ be a solution, although rather bulky. The solution with creating a wrapper implementation of `DerefMut` and hiding the ways to construct a wrapper instance from the client code works better in this particular case.